# trying to find a "simple" bug with images not appearing in bootstrap site

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

**Problem**

I'm trying to track down a "simple" bug where certain images in a codeigniter / bootstrap twitter web application do not appear.

**What I've tried so far:**

I checked the F12 tools in Firefox, and I don't see any 404s for the images in question. 
There are several images that are not appearing (all of class type "bootstrap featurette"), but for all the problematic images, the "alt" text does appear on the web page.

**Code that Does Work**
I'm bascially using the carousel example as a template. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

All the images that are a part of the carousel itself appear correctly.  And you'll notice that the path is the same as the images that don't work.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="assets/images/outside/lake2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>test lake pic</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Code That Doesn't Work**

Here's what one of the image references looks like in the html code:

```
<img class="featurette-image img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%" data-src="assets/images/inside/sittingrm1.jpg" alt="sitting room">
</div>
```

and here's the folder structure via a command prompt:

```
dev1@testsrv [~/public_html/ttest/assets/images/inside]$ ls -lah
total 11M
drwxrwxrwx 2 dotolee dotolee 4.0K Mar 24 17:19 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 dotolee dotolee 4.0K Mar 24 16:52 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dotolee dotolee 739K Mar 24 16:51 kitchen1.jpg*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dotolee dotolee 594K Mar 24 16:51 sittingrm1.jpg*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dotolee dotolee 590K Mar 24 16:51 sittingrm2.jpg*
dev1@testsrv [~/public_html/ttimes.com/assets/images/inside]$
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't see what I'm missing.
thanks

Comment: use full path of images like `data-src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/inside/sittingrm1.jpg"`

Comment: I had to change data-src to just src and then it worked.